# Wordpress CSS footer :hover

Tags: css, wordpress

It seemed to me a job for a minute, when a friend asked me to fix this. After the update of the mesmerize theme, the footer was set to default and she wanted it to be changed again. Everything went fine except: the a:hover of the footer didn't work. I couldn't fix it eighter.

I changed the CSS to:

```css
/* Footer Link-Farbe*/
.footer a {
    color: var(--color-primary);
}

/* Footer Hover-Farbe*/
.footer a:hover {
    color: var(--color-primary-light);
}
```

and also tried:

```css
/* Footer Link-Farbe*/
.footer a:link, .footer a:active, .footer a:visited {
    color: var(--color-primary);
}

/* Footer Hover-Farbe*/
.footer a:hover {
    color: var(--color-primary-light);
}
```

In the firefox developer tool i can see the link-color is working:
[screenshot of developer-tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4ArG.png)

But the :hover is not there.

But if I add the hover-rule to the developer-tool it works:
[screenshot of developer-tool with css edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8EaX.png)

I'm really lost. I hope somebody can help.
The domain ist: [www.ubuntu-ubuntu.at](https://www.ubuntu-ubuntu.com)

Comment: Domain is unreachable for me. Can you add an example of the html structure of the footer?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't find a way to delete this post. I tried to change the css endless times, checked spelling issues, ...
Then decided to post this here and ... like magic, reviewing this post and copying, paste the css into my code ... it worked.
I guess concepts like faith, power of asking, ... are not common here and as a new user/contributer I can get a lot of trouble with this first post of mine. Anyway, my problem is solved and if anybody wants to delete this post, I'm happy with that :)

Comment: @LS_ sorry, wrong domain. changed it. www.ubuntu-ubuntu.at

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a more specific selector for the hover style?

Sorry the domain you provided, didn't work so i don't know how the markup looks, but something like this:

```css
.footer .horizontal_footer_menu ul li a:hover {
    color: var(--color-primary-light);
}
```

Or try to use !important just to get things done.(It's not really recommended)

```css
.footer a:hover {
  color: var(--color-primary-light) !important;
}
```

Comment: sorry, wrong domain. changed it. www.ubuntu-ubuntu.at

Answer (score 0):

You have do declare variable in ":root" after you can use or chnage in your css classs.
in word press the backend option allow you to change footer link color using "var".
you have to change option in wordpress backend settings.

OR

You can use ":root" for overrite default settings.

```css
:root {
  --color-primary: #3f51b5;
  --color-primary-light: #1e90ff;
}

.footer .horizontal_footer_menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer .horizontal_footer_menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Footer Link-Farbe*/
.footer a {
    color: var(--color-primary);
}

/* Footer Hover-Farbe*/
.footer a:hover {
    color: var(--color-primary-light);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
        <div class="horizontal_footer_menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: have the :root already. problem is solved. Thanks
sorry, wrong domain. changed it. www.ubuntu-ubuntu.at

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this HTML code for wordpress footer hover. I have tried this in my E-commerce wordpress store and it worked fine.

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <style>
            #footer{background:#fff;position:relative}
            .footerLogo { font-size: 1.8em; font-weight: 600; color: #333; margin-bottom: 22px; display: block; }
            #footer::before{content:"";background:linear-gradient(to right,#fff 0,#535df1 50%,#fff 100%);height:5px;width:100%;position:absolute}
            .footer-wrapper{padding:50px 0;float:left;width:100%}
            img.footer-logo{margin-bottom:20px}
            ul.social-icons{margin:0; padding: 0;}
            ul.social-icons li{background:#fff;width:30px;height:30px;border:1px solid #f1f2f2;border-radius:4px;margin:3px;text-align:center; display: inline-block;}
            ul.social-icons li a{color:#6d6e71;font-size:15px;line-height:30px}
            ul.social-icons li a:hover{color:#27aae1;transition:all 1s}
            ul.footer-links { padding: 0;  list-style-type: none; position: relative;}
            ul.footer-links li{line-height:25px; padding-left: 15px; }
            ul.footer-links li:before { position: absolute; content: 'f105'; font-family: FontAwesome; left: 0;}
            ul.footer-links li a{color:#6d6e71}
            ul.footer-links li a:hover{color:#27aae1; text-decoration: none;}
            ul.contact{margin:0;padding:0}
            ul.contact li{list-style:none;padding:15px 0;border-bottom:1px solid #f1f2f2;font-size:13px;font-weight:600;line-height:15px;}
            ul.contact li i{font-size:18px;margin-right:20px;color:#27aae1} 
            .copyright{background:#231f20;text-align:center;color:#fff;padding:12px 0 4px}
            </style>
```

```html
<footer id="footer" class="bg-light mt-5">
              <div class="container">
                      <div class="footer-wrapper">
                  <div class="row">                    
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                      <a href="" class="footerLogo">Company</a>
                      <ul class="social-icons">
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-xing"></i></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                      <h5>For individuals</h5>
                      <ul class="footer-links">
                        <li><a href="">Signup</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Explore</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Finder app</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Language settings</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                      <h5>For businesses</h5>
                      <ul class="footer-links">
                        <li><a href="">Business signup</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Business login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Benefits</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Resources</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Advertise</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Setup</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                      <h5>About</h5>
                      <ul class="footer-links">
                        <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Terms</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                      <h5>Contact Us</h5>
                      <ul class="contact">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+1 (234) 123 1234</li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>info@company.com</li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>123 Any street second floor, INDIA</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="copyright">
                <p>Company © 2019. All rights reserved</p>
              </div>
                </footer>
```

I took this code from https://webdesignerwall.com/wdw-snippet/footer-with-hover-effects [Aesthetic outfits](https://aesthetry.com/)

You can learn more about this issue in another thread I found:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/footer-hover-link-wont-change/